# What's the down button do in Second Son?

Tags: infamous-second-son

In Second Son if you press the Down button on the d pad a flash of smoke appears in your hand and...nothing else seems to happen. It's "aimed" and it seems like it must serve a purpose, but what's it for? I've gotten fairly far in the game without ever using it. Happens regardless of what power you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you earn a "Karma Streak" (performing either several Good Karma actions in a row, or several Evil Karma actions in a row), you will earn the ability to use a super move by pressing Down on the D-Pad. You'll see an indicator in the upper-left corner of the screen when you've earned this ability, like this:

[image]

This ability first becomes available during the boss fight

> on top of the Space Needle.

Comment: Oh right, duh. I unlocked that ages ago but since it wasn't charged I forgot what button it was...

Comment: lol ages ago? it just came out :p